# How can I view and edit a txt using tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a method to add a button where it opens the savefile.txt and lets me edit it while using Tkinter?
My current method is just saving the file and manually opening my txt

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from MailSaverFunctions import *


def quitApp():
    errmsg = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Quit", "Save Before quitting")
    if errmsg == "yes":
        exit(-1)
    elif errmsg == "no":
        pass
    else:
        pass


def SavingInput():
    category = categoryEntry.get()
    Mail = mailEntry.get()
    password = passwordEntry.get()
    filewrite = open("SaveFile.txt", "a")
    filewrite.write(category + "----" + Mail + "----" + password+"\n")
    filewrite.close()

    categoryEntry.delete(0, END)
    mailEntry.delete(0, END)
    passwordEntry.delete(0, END)


root = Tk()

root.title("MailSaver")
savepic = PhotoImage(file="save.png")
quitpic = PhotoImage(file="close.png")

startlbl = Label(root, text="Mail saver, password saver, in addition to categpries, Also organized!! ")

lblcategory = Label(root, text="Category", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, fg="red")
lblmail = Label(root, text="Mail",  bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
lblpassword = Label(root, text="Password", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)

categoryEntry = Entry(root)
mailEntry = Entry(root)
passwordEntry = Entry(root)


savebtn = Button(root, image=savepic, command=SavingInput)
quitbtn = Button(root, image=quitpic, command=quitApp)

lblcategory.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=E)
lblmail.grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=E)
lblpassword.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=E)

categoryEntry.grid(row=1, column=4)
mailEntry.grid(row=2, column=4)
passwordEntry.grid(row=3, column=4)

savebtn.grid(row=4, column=3)
quitbtn.grid(row=4, column=4)


lblcategory.configure(font="70")
lblmail.configure(font="100")
lblpassword.configure(font="85")

root.mainloop()
```

just need to make a viewing window and a editing window to edit infile credintals.

Comment: No, there is no predefined method to do that in `tkinter`.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what You want but it seems as simple as just using `tkinter.filedialog` to ask for the file, then read that file, insert the contents in a Text widget, then when You are done with editing, read the Text widget and save the contents to the same file

Comment: can you elaborate the usage of ```tkinter.filedialog```

Comment: Tkinter is just a UI module. Unless you want the user to select the file to be edited, you do not need the filedialog. You can feed the text data using your methods into a text widget, let the user change it, then when they are done (e.g. Click on a button to save it), read the contents of the widget and save the file using your methods.